# Starting threads in a schuled task in Spring Web Application?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I'm using Spring Boot for a web server, and there is a scheduled task that I have to run every hour. It involves making thousands of http requests which I have stored in a list (retrieved and set from a different endpoint), which obviously will take long. To speed things up, inside the scheduled method I start up four threads to each handle a fourth of the http calls that I have to make. There is absolutely no risk of deadlock or race-conditions. It's rather simple: I have 1000 http requests to make every hour, thread one will handle the first 250, thread two will handle the next 250, etc.

```
@Component
public MyComponent {

    private List<URI> uris;
    ...

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000)
    public void process() {

        List<List<URI>> uriList = //method that will divide up the uri's into equal fourths

        uriList.forEach(uri -> new Thread(new URIProcessor(uri)).start());
```

Would this be an acceptable practice? I know Spring offers its own abstractions for multithreading but I feel such a simple task shouldn't require using them.

Comment: I do not have a lot of experience with multithreading but it sounds fine. Did you consider using parallel stream?

Answer (score 0):

one important point to consider, you have configured this process method to run in every 1 hour, however here you don't care what happened to the ones raised before !!

Example:1) Think about this if the previous threads are still running because the URI opening is taking long, in this case you will end up increasing the threads every hour !! So ensure you test that your thread completion time

2) If you thread gets struck say due to technical reason what would you like it to do then ? this needs to be accounted for.

One solution is set a global variable/indicator say a file or database entry to tell new starting process that old is completed else some way to inform you say by logging exceptions or shooting email to you etc...

Please accept and like if you appreciate my gesture to help with my ideas n experience.

Answer (score 0):

You may think of something like this to handle start, stop and restarts

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class AutoTimerService {
private ScheduledExecutorService  scheduledThreadPool = null;
private Runnable autoTask = null;
private Long currentDelayIntervalInMs; 
private boolean isTaskRunning = false;

public AutoTimerService(String name, Long delayIntervalInMs, Runnable autoTask){
    if (name == null || name.isEmpty()){
        throw new RuntimeException("Please specify a friendly name to the timer service");
    }

    if (autoTask == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("Please specify task to be scheduled of type java.util.TimerTask");
    }

    this.autoTask = autoTask;
    this.currentDelayIntervalInMs = delayIntervalInMs;
}

public synchronized void startTask() {
    if (!isTaskRunning) {
        scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);;
        scheduledThreadPool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(autoTask, 0,  currentDelayIntervalInMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        isTaskRunning = true;
    }
}

public synchronized void resetTask(Long delayIntervalInMs) {
    stopTask();
    this.currentDelayIntervalInMs = delayIntervalInMs;
    startTask();
}

public synchronized void stopTask() {
    if (isTaskRunning){
        scheduledThreadPool.shutdown();
        while(!scheduledThreadPool.isTerminated());

        isTaskRunning = false;
    }
}
```